# Overwriting Memory with pointers in C

Tags: c

I had a question about my recent code.

I was writing a method to copy a block of memory, whose start was represented by one pointer, to another block of memory whose start is represented by another pointer. The method is something like this:

```
void copyMem(const uint8_t* const base, uint32_t start, 
                            uint32_t end, uint32_t length) {
for(uint32_t x = 0; x < Length; x++) {
    *(base + end + x) = *(base + start + x);
}
}
```

"base" refers to the start of the memory block, and "start" and "end" refer to sections within that block (so, if base was, say, 21353646, then "start" could be 10, which would refer to 213536**5**6, and end could be 20, which would refer to 213536**6**6).

My precondition specifies that the memory doesn't overlap, so I don't need to worry about that. Above is my attempt to write something that would copy a memory block from "start" to "end", but it fails, giving me the error that it's an assignment of a read-only location. Which I think I understand is because base is const, so I can't actually modify it.

But how else am I supposed to overwrite the section of memory if I can't modify the memory in the first place?

Comment: First is this an assignment or self prescribed puzzle because there are functions already that do what you want. `memmove()` handles overlapping memory.

Comment: Removing the `const` attributes will solve.

Comment: Why do you only pass a single pointer? You cannot address every possible memory location with an integer offset from a pointer.

Comment: @1sand0s both, sort of. It's a problem in a C book I'm reading.

ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira I don't think I'm allowed to change around the argument types.

Comment: Why not just keep it simple and take arguments like the standard memcpy() does, and do the math before calling the function.  or call it like `memcpy(dst + dstoffset, src + srcoffset, len)` ?

Comment: Are you saying I should use memcopy instead of trying to modify the pointer directly? Is that the only way to do it?

Comment: I'm saying keep it simple.  Don't complicate it more than necessary, unless it's a learning exercise and those are the constraints of the problem. The answer you got looks pretty good below. I up voted it, as I think you should, and be sure to click the √ next to the answer that works for you, to accept it, if it works for you.  -- that's how question answerers on this site get 'paid' :-)

Comment: If your book contains an exercise that asks you to implement a function with exactly the signature and behavior you have given, then your best bet would to be to get a better book.  The function signature is incompatible with the specified behavior, and though you could force it, an introductory text oughtn't to be pointing you in that direction.

Comment: @1sand0s memmove would probably be a little safer.

Comment: @1sand0s so would it be as simple as writing: memcpy(base + end, base + start, Length) ?

Comment: If the object of the exercise is to learn how to implement something like `memcpy`, just calling `memcpy` can't be the solution.

Comment: @Tigger12 if you need to write memcpy, just do a simple one and then pass the arguments as I showed. I'll post an ultra simple memcpy example.

Comment: @Tigger12 See my answer below.  Better to let memcpy take void * and then cast it into 8-bit quantities to do the byte-by-byte copying from one to the other. Keeps it more generic.  As far as the base + start, base + end you showed, whatever arithmetic you use to arrive at a source and destination address is fine. Or no adding at all - e.g. passing in constants, literals, or pointers.  It just needs two addresses and a length, is the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how else am I supposed to overwrite the section of memory if I can't modify the memory in the first place?

Easy: remove the first const.
It says that the memory you point to is constant... so obviously you cannot modify it.

If you want to be const correct you could just go the memcpy way and have a pointer to non constant memory as the target and a pointer to constant memory as the source.

Also: Why don't you simply use memcpy? In most cases the compiler will replace memcpy by something processor/operating system specific that will copy the data more efficient than most trivial solutions you might come up with.

And last but not least you can cast away the const inside the function,
though I would not recommend that. IMHO the cleanest way would be using memcpy in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
void memcpy(void *dst, void *src, int len) {
     for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
         *(uint8_t *)dst++ = *(uint8_t *)src++
}
```

To call it:

```
memcpy(addr1 + offset1, addr2 + offset2, len);
```

It's the same effect of the parameters you showed in your code example, except you're merely doing the math outside the function and keeping the function simple and generic.

I'm saying you can accomplish the same thing this way, but the function is simple and easy to read and very generic.

Comment: Ah thanks, makes sense! I do get an annoying warning from the compiler that "bleaaaah you're bypassing the const this way and modifying memory", but whatever! :D

Comment: @Tigger12 You can probably add a pragma near that function or use a compiler option to suppress that kind of warning. What OS and compiler?